# Simple Servlet page navigation for multiple actions not working

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am new to Java EE. Working on demo app. Right now have to work with JSP & Servlet with JDBC for learning.

UserServlet.java manage navigation to all user related list, edit and delete operations. All 3 JSP pages has links to navigate that it. JSP pages are at /WEB-INF/admin/. See the **dispatch method**.

***Someone please tell me what is wrong and how to use the navigation. Fix it.***

**ERROR for all the links:**

```
type Status report

message /Navigation/user/delete

description The requested resource (/Navigation/user/delete) is not available.
```

**SERVLET:**

```
package com.myapp.web;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/user/")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UserServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

        // String action = req.getServletPath();
        String action = req.getPathInfo();
        System.out.println("doGet action = " + action);

        if ((action == null) || (action.equals("/list"))) {

            System.out.println("/UserList.jsp");
            dispatch(req, res, "/UserList.jsp");

        } else if (action.equals("/edit")) {

            System.out.println("/UserEdit.jsp");
            dispatch(req, res, "/UserEdit.jsp");

        } else if (action.equals("/delete")) {

            System.out.println("/UserDelete.jsp");
            dispatch(req, res, "/UserDelete.jsp");

        }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

        String action = req.getPathInfo();
        System.out.println("doPost action = " + action);

        if (action.equals("/edit")) {

            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/user/list");

        } else if (action.equals("/delete")) {

            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/user/list");

        }
    }

    protected void dispatch(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, String page)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String path = "/WEB-INF/admin" + page;
        System.out.println(path);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(req, res);
    }
}
```

**JSP Page links. All got same**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>

<tags:layout path="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" title="list of Users">
    <jsp:attribute name="search">
        <tags:search />
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
        <span class="right" style="margin-bottom: 3px;"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/list" class="btn btn-success">List</a></span>
        <br />
        <span class="right" style="margin-bottom: 3px;"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/edit" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a></span>
        <br />
        <span class="right" style="margin-bottom: 3px;"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/delete" class="btn btn-success">Delete</a></span>
    </jsp:body>
</tags:layout>
```

Comment: `@WebServlet("/user/*")` isn't enough? BTW have you considered [tag:jax-rs]?

Comment: @tomasz-nurkiewicz, When I use /* than at the start I get url like http://localhost:8080/Navigation/user/* . Do you want me add extra condition like this ((action == null) || (action == "*") || (action.equals("/list"))) ?

Comment: I don't quite understand. By saying `"/user/*"` you instruct the container to handle all incoming URLs starting with `/user/`, e.g. `/user/delete`, `/user/foo`...

Comment: If I add like @WebServlet("/user/*") than none of the doGet condition is hit at the start when servlet is load and I see the url like  "localhost:8080/Navigation/user/*" where it should load  localhost:8080/Navigation/user/list at the load of servlet. I hope you get my point?

Comment: @tomasz-nurkiewicz, any help on my above comment please.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you use href to page /Navigation/user/delete and this page does not exist. You must create this page to remove error, but it don't resolve your problem.

You analyze url when executing req.getPathInfo(). As I understand you have pages with user list and for editing one, but don't have separate page for delete them. Separate logic for deleting user.

```
String action = req.getPathInfo();//here you analyze url
String actionProperty = req.getParameter("action");//here you analyze property
if(actionProperty.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
    //you code for delete action
}
```

and replace your link

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/delete" class="btn btn-success">Delete</a>
```

with this one

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user?action=delete" class="btn btn-success">Delete</a>
```